# Problem with UV unwrapping. Why this happening?

Tags: uv

Why this is happening? I'm trying to unwrapping part of object then pin it and add that square.

[image]

[image]

[File you can download.](https://blend-exchange.com/b/qlZ3XSp8/)

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Comment: I'm not native english speaker

Comment: This happens exactly when i use Transform to sphere but why i don't know.

Comment: I guess Blender does not like topology there.

Comment: Overlapping issue

Comment: Try A, M, B, also check if there are internal faces (hide the faces near the problematic area and see if there were faces behind that.